# Saving file to GCS not working in Next.js production build

Tags: typescript, stream, upload, google-cloud-storage, next.js14

These are the modules I am using.

```
"@google-cloud/storage": "^7.7.0"
"next": "14.1.0"
```

This is the code.

```
"use server";

import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";
import fs from "fs";

const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
});
const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.GCP_BUCKET_NAME || '');

export async function saveToCloud() {
  const readable = fs.createReadStream("sample.png");
  const blob = bucket.file("sample_on_cloud.png");
  const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();

  try {
    await new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        readable.pipe(blobStream)
          .on('error', reject)
          .on('finish', resolve)
      }
    )
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('getting error: ', e);  // in production build, I am getting this error.
    return {error: true}
  }
  
  return {success: true}
}
```

In development environment, it works perfectly.
All the environment variables are working correctly.
But when it comes to production version, it give me error.

[image: Error Screen]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you find your solution? I'm having the exact same issue and don't understand why. If not what was your work around?

Comment: @Anselme, I couldn't find the solution. The thing is it worked in lower versions of Next.js but not in next14. So it turned out we decided to save files to google firestore, not GCS. And that worked.
And as far as I am concerned, sending `PUT` request in Next14 server actions is working odd. Just because, I realized saving files to GCS internally sends `PUT` request to the google cloud file servers. If it helped, I would be happy.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an issue with next.js

Adding the following to your next.config.mjs next config property should help

```
experimental:{
  serverMinification: false
},
```

Comment: So did this snippet fixed problem?